# Hello, I am opening the ipynb file with VS Code. I see things like that. How can I fix this

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am opening the ipynb file with VS Code. I see things like that. How can I fix this. Can you help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNj6x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `Python` on your computer and the `Python extension` in the VSCode?

Because the python environment has not been activated in your picture.

[image]

[image]